# Understanding this jQuery filter function

Tags: jquery

I am staring at the following piece of code that searches a htmltable but unable to figure it out. Can anybody please explain it line by line

```
(function ($) {

    $('#filter').keyup(function () {

        var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
        $('.employee tr').hide();
        $('.employee tr').filter(function () {
            return rex.test($(this).text());
        }).show();

    })

}(jQuery));
```

Also I have about 1000 rows in my table. Performance wise are there any issue you see if I use this code?

Comment: In response to your question about performance, you can chain the `hide` and `filter` commands together to prevent a duplicate DOM lookup

Comment: @Ninsly Thanks. Can you show how?

Comment: Did you mean like this ? $('.employee tr').hide().filter(function () {

Comment: Yes, exactly! You already found all the elements using the selector `.employee tr`, and calling `hide` does not affect the elements in the jQuery array, so you can call filter on it directly afterward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 3: When a key is released (when you take your finger off the key)

Line 5: Creates a regular expression object that matches to the string that has been typed into the filter input box.

Line 6: Hides every employee row

Line 7-9: This takes every employee row and applies a filter.  The function within the filter is applied to every row of the employee table and returns true or false based on whether its text matches the Regular Expression (which is using the value from the filter input.)  All of the results of the filter that return true then have .show() called on them.